# Finding a basis of the null space with a specific structure

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let `A` be an nxm matrix and `rank(A) = r`. Let `N` be the matrix whose columns span the right null space of `A`. How can I find `N` where `N` has the following structure (as a matlab code):

```
N = [eye(m-r); P]
```

Where `eye(m-r)` is the `(m-r) x (m-r)` identity matrix and `P` is the remaining piece of `A`.

Comment: Is the *Reduced row echelon form* `rref` what you are looking for?

Comment: A null space basis itself can be found using `null`.